# how do you create map based heatmap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have location based response time data, per states. I would like to be able to create a map type of heatmap:

there is my df:

```
structure(list(DATE_TIME = structure(c(1369419660, 1369419720, 
1369419720, 1369419780, 1369419780, 1369419840, 1369419840, 1369419900, 
1369419960, 1369419960, 1369419960, 1369420020, 1369420020, 1369420020, 
1369420020, 1369420080, 1369420080, 1369420080, 1369420080, 1369420140, 
1369420140, 1369420140, 1369420140, 1369420200, 1369420200, 1369420260, 
1369420260, 1369420260, 1369420260, 1369420260), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SITE = c("Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", "Logon to My Accounts", 
"Logon to My Accounts"), RESPONSE_TIME = c(7.069, 7.056, 11.535, 
7.33, 9.566, 5.21, 6.483, 6.652, 8.222, 9.368, 10.055, 6.301, 
6.33, 7.802, 10.132, 6.241, 6.997, 7.499, 7.823, 6.173, 6.912, 
7.979, 10.128, 7.072, 7.65, 6.048, 7.681, 8.08, 8.272, 9.583), 
    AVAIL_PERCENT = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L), AGENT = c(45869L, 45540L, 45672L, 45036L, 
    45421L, 42627L, 44981L, 42432L, 45869L, 45693L, 42108L, 40522L, 
    40521L, 45540L, 45672L, 40517L, 45036L, 45421L, 40511L, 42627L, 
    44981L, 40370L, 40369L, 40368L, 42432L, 40282L, 45693L, 42108L, 
    40296L, 45869L), LOCATION = c("seattle", "hartford", "houston", 
    "san diego", "montreal", "new york", "philadelphia", "chicago", 
    "seattle", "dallas", "pittsburgh", "miami", "denver", "hartford", 
    "houston", "atlanta", "san diego", "montreal", "milwaukee", 
    "new york", "philadelphia", "vancouver", "toronto", "calgary", 
    "chicago", "san jose", "dallas", "pittsburgh", "mexico city", 
    "seattle")), .Names = c("DATE_TIME", "SITE", "RESPONSE_TIME", 
"AVAIL_PERCENT", "AGENT", "LOCATION"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this:

```
require(maps)
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(map_id = LOCATION)) + geom_map(aes(fill = RESPONSE_TIME), map = states_map) + expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
```

any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: where does the `states_map` object come from?

Comment: @rmk I was trying to do this states_map<-map_data("state")

Comment: @rmk I dont need the sub regions.

Comment: Is there a problem in using cities data to plot a states map? `setdiff(df$LOCATION, unique(states_map[,5]))`

Comment: @rmk, sorry I just realized what you were asking, either way is fine.

Comment: It would be great if you could accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert `df$LOCATION` to corresponding states.

Load datasets:

```
data(us.cities)
data(state, package="datasets")

c2s = sapply(df$LOCATION,function(x){
            us.cities[grep(x,us.cities$name,ignore.case=T)[1],2]})

> head(c2s)
  seattle  hartford   houston san diego  montreal  new york 
     "WA"      "CT"      "TX"      "CA"        NA      "NY"
```

Get state abbreviations:

```
a2n = tolower(state.name)
names(a2n) = state.abb
df = cbind(df,a2n[c2s])

> head(df)
            DATE_TIME                 SITE RESPONSE_TIME AVAIL_PERCENT AGENT
1 2013-05-24 14:21:00 Logon to My Accounts         7.069           100 45869
2 2013-05-24 14:22:00 Logon to My Accounts         7.056           100 45540
3 2013-05-24 14:22:00 Logon to My Accounts        11.535           100 45672
4 2013-05-24 14:23:00 Logon to My Accounts         7.330           100 45036
5 2013-05-24 14:23:00 Logon to My Accounts         9.566           100 45421
6 2013-05-24 14:24:00 Logon to My Accounts         5.210           100 42627
   LOCATION  c2s    a2n[c2s]
1   seattle   WA  washington
2  hartford   CT connecticut
3   houston   TX       texas
4 san diego   CA  california
5  montreal <NA>        <NA>
6  new york   NY    new york

colnames(df)[7:8] = c("State.Abb","State")
```

Leave out Canadian states and plot:

```
ggplot(df[!is.na(df$State),], aes(map_id = State)) + geom_map(aes(fill = RESPONSE_TIME), map = states_map) + expand_limits(x = states_map$long, y = states_map$lat)
```

[image]

To get the whole map, just append the remaining states to the bottom of `df`

Comment: I need to see the whoe map, with all states and hightlight the states that I have the data for.

Comment: One way to map cities to states is using `data(us.cities)` and looking for matches: `us.cities[grep(df$LOCATION[1],us.cities$name,ignore.case=T),]`